# How to integrate Anyline OCR SDK made for Cordova into Ionic2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I´m new to Ionic2, but experienced in web development. Just learning new platform at the moment.

So I have tried to integrate the Anyline OCR SDK
https://github.com/Anyline/anyline-ocr-cordova-module

but I am failing, it seems to me that the plugin is written in Javascript and not compatible with TS but I´m not sure...

Is there anyone out there that could help?

Thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you still need help with that, but for those out there who are looking for a working solution, here is mine:

1 - Add the Anyline Plugin to your project `cordova plugin add io-anyline-cordova`

2 - Create a new file `ionic g provider anyline`

3 - add this code to your **anyline.ts** file:

```
export class OCR {

constructor() {
    if (anylineScan === undefined) {
        var anylineScan = {};
    }
}

anylineScan = {

    onResult: function (result) {
        console.log("MRZ result: " + JSON.stringify(result));
        //do what you want here with the result
    },

    onError: function (error) {
        console.log("scanning error");
    },

    scan: function () {
        var licenseKey = "enterYourLicenceKeyHere";
        try {
            (<any>window).cordova.exec(this.onResult, this.onError, "AnylineSDK", "OCR", [licenseKey, {
                "captureResolution":"1080p",
                //your other config setting here
            }]);
        }
        catch (e){
            console.log("Cannot open scan view: ERROR occurred");
        }
    }
}
```

4 - Add the file references to your **app.module.ts** file

```
import { OCR } from '../yourFolderName/anyline';
...
providers: [Storage, OCR]
```

5 - In your **page.ts** file add the following call:

```
this.anyline.anylineScan.scan();
```

**Important!** It will not work in the browser, make sure you run `ionic platform add ios` (or android) and run the app on a device.

This should work!

Good luck and happy coding :-)

Comment: Hi Romaan Lee, thanks your answer - going to try this now! Will keep you posted :D

Comment: No problem. Let me know if you have any trouble.